# Multiple parameters in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC and am stuck at this. I was trying to create a filter for name, category, type, Min Value, Max value but when redirected to another view it only shows three parameters but without other values.

Controller  (DetailController)

```
public ActionResult FilteredResult(string searchedLocation, string Type, string PCName, string MinValue, string MaxValue)
{
    var A = searchedLocation;
    var B = Type;
    var C = PCName;
    var D = MinValue;
    var E = MaxValue;
    return View();
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilteredResult", "Detail", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <form>
        <h4 style="color: #ed145b;">Find the right property for you</h4>
        <ul class="form-style-1">
            <li>
                @Html.TextBox("Location", ViewBag.Location as string , new { @class = "field-long" })
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.DropDownList("Type", (SelectList)ViewBag.TypeList, "Select" , new { @class = "field-select" })
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.DropDownList("Category", (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryList, "Select" ,new { @class = "field-select" })
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" class="field-long" readonly style="border:0; color:#ee2265; font-weight:bold;">
            </li>
            <li class="clearfix"> @Html.TextBox("MinValue", ViewBag.MinValue as string, new { @class = "Minprice field-long", disabled = "true" })
                @Html.TextBox("MaxValue", ViewBag.MaxValue as string, new { @class = "Maxprice field-long", disabled = "true" })
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="slider-range"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-primary" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
```

[image]

After clicking on search it shows like this. Only the data from dropdown is shown and other parameter like Minvalue and max value is not shown in the url. Location is showing

[image]

Can anyone help me on how I can successfully get data in the required field in the controller?

Comment: How do you want to use declared variables (`var A = searchedLocation;
            var B = Type;
            var C = PCName;
            var D = MinValue;
            var E = MaxValue;`) in FilteredResult? You do not pass any data to View.

Comment: i want to pass data from view in the form
`http://localhost:1044/Detail/FilteredResult?Location=asdf &Type= 2&Category=1&MinValue=12&MaxValue=323421215`

Comment: First thing you should do is to put this properties inside a model, to clean your code and bind it easily

Comment: I havent placed the Location Property inside the model but the data is assigned to Location in the URL. But by same process i have created textbox MinValue & MaxValue  and its is not shown in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your MinValue and MaxValue textboxes have `disabled="true"` attribute. Disabled inputs won't be submitted

```
@Html.TextBox("MinValue", ViewBag.MinValue as string, new { @class = "Minprice field-long", disabled = "true" })
@Html.TextBox("MaxValue", ViewBag.MaxValue as string, new { @class = "Maxprice field-long", disabled = "true" })
```

You should remove the `disabled` attribute

```
@Html.TextBox("MinValue", ViewBag.MinValue as string, new { @class = "Minprice field-long" })
@Html.TextBox("MaxValue", ViewBag.MaxValue as string, new { @class = "Maxprice field-long" })
```

If you want to make those textboxes non editable, use `readonly` attribute instead

```
@Html.TextBox("MinValue", ViewBag.MinValue as string, new { @class = "Minprice field-long", @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.TextBox("MaxValue", ViewBag.MaxValue as string, new { @class = "Maxprice field-long", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using disabled attribute true that means it fetches data from database but will not show  on View so either make disabled = "false" or remove this attribute.